# Dua for marriage

Tags: nikah, dua

Forgive me if this appears to be a dumb question but I am asking here anyway given how helpful everybody is here. Do you know of any surah/dua that will help me to marry sooner and the kind of man I want to be with? I am of marriageable age but making too little progress there. It feels like the toughest thing ever. Currently my household has become emotionally abusive so I am even more desperate to leave and start a new peaceful life. I beg my sisters and brothers on this platform, if you know any good and fruitful dua for a good and quick marriage, kindly share it with me.

Answer (score 1):

﷽

Assalaamualekum my sister in faith.

One of the most important things for a believer is to not lose hope in Allaah's(ﷻ)Mercy.

Allaah (ﷻ) says in Qur'an (93:5,6)

> For indeed, with hardship [will be] ease. (5) Indeed, with hardship [will be] ease. (6)

Notice that Allaah (ﷻ), repeated it twice to reassure His believing slaves.

Another thing is to always keep in mind that we are being tested. In all situations we praise Allaah (ﷻ) and we need to adopt one of the two things for the sake of Allaah (ﷻ)

**Shukr** When things happen in ways such that we are pleased with them

**Sabr** When things do not happen in ways such that we are pleased with them

And Allaah (ﷻ) says in the Qur'an (2:153)

> O you who have believed, seek help through patience and prayer. Indeed, Allah is with the patient. (153)

So make lots of dua to Allaah (ﷻ) and have patience of His sake.

Also, you mentioned

> *I beg my sisters and brothers on this platform,*

Allaah (ﷻ) has honored the believers with Eeman. Do not beg to anyone except Him alone. Allaah (ﷻ), my Lord and yours is closer to you than any one of us could possibly be.

Coming to dua for quick marriage, we do not find specific dua in Qur'an and Sunnah. But there are a few things that you can do-

1. Be regular about five daily prayers.
2. Pray tahajjud in the last third of the night and make lots of dua after prayer, as this is the time for acceptance of dua.
3. Contemplate about your past sins and the ones you might be doing currently. Sincerely repent. And make lots of Istagfar, especially [Syed-ul- Istighfar](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1875)
4. Involve in extra good deeds, charity etc.
5. Pray for your Aakhirat more than anything else in this worldly life, (even marriage). As aakhirat is what matters at the end.

May Allaah (ﷻ) make things easier for you.

Comment: Walaikumassalam brother/sister. Many thanks for your eloquent and eye-opening answer. May Allah (ﷻ) shower His blessings upon you for the kind and informative reply.